# Reading from XML file in memory using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml

I use code below to open zip archive in memory.

```
using (var leagueFile = File.OpenRead(openFileDialog.FileName))
using (var package = new ZipArchive(leagueFile, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (var team in package.Entries)
    {
        if (team.Name.EndsWith(".xml"))
        {
            _xmlHandler.Import<Player>(team.FullName, Encoding.UTF8);
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to deserialize with my `Import<T>()` method, app crashes due to file wasn't found.

```
public T Import<T>(string fileName, Encoding encoding) where T : class, new()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.UnknownNode += serializer_UnknownNode;
    serializer.UnknownAttribute += serializer_UnknownAttribute;

    var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(fileName, encoding));
    var po = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    return po;
}
```

The problem is that app is searching for `fileName` in the `bin` directory of application. Not in `stream` (?) of zip archive. Is there a way to do this with `XmlSerializer` class?

Comment: Yes, it will try to load the file from the bin directory, because you are creating a new `StreamReader` instance with the specified fileName. If you want to open the file from the zip stream, Instead of passing the `fileName` as your method argument, pass the stream,  received from the zip, so that you don't have to create a new stream out of the file name. You have to modify your method arguments though

Comment: @zafar `Create` method of `XmlReader` allows only `Stream` as a parameter. It looks like `ZipArchive` doesn't fall here.

Comment: I mean to say, modify your method like this:

`public T Import<T>(Stream input, Encoding encoding) where T : class, new()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.UnknownNode += serializer_UnknownNode;
    serializer.UnknownAttribute += serializer_UnknownAttribute;

    var reader = XmlReader.Create(input);
    var po = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    return po;
}`

Comment: Read returns `None`: https://i.gyazo.com/9a587dafa247fafd1577346a9190b8c8.png

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code as below:

```
using (var leagueFile = File.OpenRead(openFileDialog.FileName))
using (var package = new ZipArchive(leagueFile, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (var team in package.Entries)
    {
        if (team.Name.EndsWith(".xml"))
        {
            using(var xmlStream = team.Open())
            {
                _xmlHandler.Import<Player>(xmlStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                //...
            }

        }
    }
}

public T Import<T>(Stream input, Encoding encoding) where T : class, new()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.UnknownNode += serializer_UnknownNode;
    serializer.UnknownAttribute += serializer_UnknownAttribute;

    var reader = XmlReader.Create(input);
    var po = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    return po;
}
```